# Not able to open TopCoder Arena on Mac

Tags: java, macos, exception

I'm running Mac OSX 10.8.3 with the java version being 1.6.0_51.

I downloaded the ContestAppletProd.jnlp and tried opening it, but it failed with the following exception:

[image: TopCoder Exception]

Has anyone faced the issue before? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: does it not require java 1.7 ?